# input type="color" that changes color of element

Tags: java, html, firefox-addon

I'm working on a popup extension that changes color of a div element. This is what I tried:

**JSON**

```
{

  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "div color",
  "version": "1.0",

  "description": "Changes color of div",
  "icons": {
    "48": "icon.png"
  },

  "permissions": [
    "activeTab"
  ],

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon",
    "default_title": "div",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },

}
```

**Popup**

```
<html>
<head><script src="popup.js"></script></head>
<body>
<input type="color" id="pickcolor">
</body>
</html>
```

I don't really know what to do for javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an onchange-event like

```
<input type="color" id="pickcolor" onchange="changeColor(this.value)"/>
```

Add this function to your JavaScript:

```
function changeColor(c) {
    document.getElementById("elementId").style.backgroundColor = c;
}
```

where `"elementId"` is the ID of the div you want to change colors and it should work. Note that you can only change the color of an element in your popup this way. If you want to change the style of a div on the website, you need to create a [Content Script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts).